# Share screenshot to facebook/twitter using cocos2d-x on IOS

Tags: cocos2d-x, objective-c++, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am porting my game from cocos2d (obj-c) to cocos2d-x 2.x (c++) but i am really struggling with getting the social features to work. Is it possible in any way to use the code below which works flawless in native objective-c and cocos2d.

**Take screenshot**

```
- (UIImage*) takeScreenShot
{
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    CCLayerColor* blankLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 0) width:winSize.width height:winSize.height];

    blankLayer.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);

    CCRenderTexture* rtx = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width height:winSize.height];

    [rtx begin];
    [blankLayer visit];
    //[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] visit];
        [layer_main visit];
        [rtx end];

        return [rtx getUIImage];
    }
```

**Post on facebook**

```
    - (void)share_score_facebook: (id) sender{
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")){
        [AppVariables showAlert:@"Outdated iOS" message:@"You must have atleast iOS 6.0 to use the social features.\nPlease update to a newer iOS."];
        return;
    }

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];

    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIImage * screenshot = [self takeScreenShot];

    SLComposeViewController *faceBookPost = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [faceBookPost setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Game on! Just scored %d on Game. Can you Beat it?",total_score]];
    [faceBookPost addImage:screenshot];
    [faceBookPost addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL_HERE"]];

    [[app navController] presentViewController:faceBookPost animated:YES completion:nil];
    faceBookPost.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
    {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
        [[app navController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    };
}
```

Comment: Can you please first check if you are getting a `UIImage` Object? When I did it recently, I saved image in Documnets directory and then used it from there to share on FB. I was able to do that successfully.

Comment: Well this is not the code i am using now due to the fact that it is objective-c and cocos2d-x uses c++. The code above works without any problems and stores the image in a buffer and the perfect scenario would be to get this working in some way on cocos2d-x. Are you using cocos2d-x?

Comment: yes.. I am using cocos2d-x..

Comment: Could you please share the bridge that you are using between obj-c and c++?

Comment: `rtx->saveToFile("screenshot1.png", kCCImageFormatPNG);`

Once you save this...


    `std::string filePath =  CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath() +
    "screenshot1.png";
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:filePath.c_str()]];`

Now you can share this UIImage Object...

Comment: Use this de in Cocos2d-x to create Image..

Answer (score 0):

You can compile any Objective-C code with cocos2d-x, but you need modify your code to adapt for cocos2d-x API. You want to take a screenshot and post it to Facebook, right? How about using the following instead of your Objective-C code?

- [Cocos2d-x v3.2-alpha0 Released! - Added utils::captureScreen to take screeshot](http://cocos2d-x.org/news/287)

  - [v3.2-alpha0 ccUtils.cpp](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/e81db73b0a180c50a23e5fb6516eef8f420ded4e/cocos/base/ccUtils.cpp) seems it is able to work on earlier version of cocos2d-x
- [Screw - aims to bring native Facebook SDK functionalities to cocos2d-x](https://github.com/hiepnd/Screw)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i really dont want to be using an alpha version of c2dx :/ It would be great if i could understand how to work with the social.framework using cocos2dx